# I cannot see the folder named "Temp" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Before upgrading to Windows 7, I was using Vista and I had a folder D:\Temp. After upgrading, I cannot see the folder any more. Even when I show all the hidden folders/files. But I know it is there, 'cause I can see all files under this directory if I type D:\Temp in the Explorer address bar and press Enter. Any body knows why?

**Copied from an answer**

I already checked the option in Organize - Folder and Search Options - View - Show hidden files, folders, and drivers. And one hidden folder "MSOCache" was displayed. But not the Temp directory. It was not a system folder. I created it myself.

I cannot find File in the Windows Explorer...

Comment: everything.exe from voidtools.com reveals more than 20 Temp folders in my WIN7 system - excluding those in windows.old - It is very useful for finding files or folders when you only remember part of the name or path.

Answer (score 4):

This probably has to do with the "Hide hidden and system files" Explorer setting.

In the Explorer window, it will be something like <kbd>File</kbd> (1st entry in the topmost menu) => <kbd>Folder options</kbd> => <kbd>View</kbd> Tab => <kbd>Show hidden files, folders, and drives</kbd> (Cheers @Marko for the english labels!)

Comment: You cheekily scored 10 rep there @Pekka :)

Comment: @Marko: Quick, let's all give him -1s! :P

Comment: `Daily vote limit reached`. It's your lucky day @Pekka :)

Comment: @Marko hahaha! *phew*

Comment: In all seriousness I agree, people aren't voting to close/migrate quickly enough. See how I can still take my time writing this comment?

Comment: @BoltClock true. And it's just one more missing.

Comment: Hahahahha! By the way it's Tools -> Folder Options ->Show hidden files, folders, and drives. Just noticed Microsoft put a redundant comma after `files`. Bloody illiterates.

Comment: Comment comment comment comment comment. *Edit:* Oh, here it is now. +1 for you, @Pekka.

Comment: @Pekka Why are you using `kbd` for menu options? Those aren't keys I can find on my keyboard. *Goes off to look for a keyboard with `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`*

Comment: @YiJiang they are all next to the "Any" key :) Nah, just to add some fanciness, no deeper reason

Comment: Haha @Pekka it's still incorrect. The first item in the topmost menu is `File`. Maybe they put Tools first since all you Germans are engineers. Hahaha

Comment: @Marko ahahaha! No, I suspect we mean different menus, I have a shortcut menu of some sort in my Explorer windows. Only when I click the "menu" button to the right, I get the proper `File / Edit / etc.` menu.

Comment: @Pekka Oh okay I think I know what you mean! I'm still laughing at my joke, how sad is that? Hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

I already checked the option in Organize - Folder and Search Options - View - Show hidden files, folders, and drivers. And one hidden folder "MSOCache" was displayed. But not the Temp directory. It was not a system folder. I created it myself.

I cannot find File in the Windows Explorer...

Answer (score 1):

In the same option window (Folder and Search Options -> View
uncheck "Hide Protected Operating System Files" and verify.

However, I suspect that will not be the case. Another way to verify if it is an explorer issue try this:

1. Start->Run -> Type cmd
2. At the command prompt, type -> D: -> cd\temp

If the last command does not give an error but changes to the folder, then it is something to do with Explorer.

Sorry if I'm troubleshooting but perhaps it might help :)